# Match the signature hash to match hash in application code for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, hmac

I have an endpoint that receives a `payload` with `timestamp` and `signature` values in the header. In addition to this, I also have a `SecretKey` that's saved elsewhere.

For authenticating that the payload is coming from a trusted source I do the following:

```
public bool Authenticate(payload, timestamp, signature)
{
    // concat the timestamp header value with the serialized payload
    var stringified = string.Concat(timestamp, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));

    // retrieve secret key
    string secretKey = getSecretKey();

    // compute hash
    var hash = new HMACSHA256(secretKey.ConvertStringToByteArray());
    var output = hash.ComputeHash(valueToDigest.ConvertStringToByteArray());

    return output == signature.ConvertStringToByteArray();
}

// an extension method I wrote that converts the string to Byte[]
public static Byte[] ConvertStringToByteArray(this string input)
{
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(input);
}
```

In my test how can I get the hash (`signature`) included in the payload header to match the hash I calculate using the `secretKey`, so that the `return output == signature.ConvertStringToByteArray()` condition is met?

EDIT: Updated approach

```
public bool Authenticate(MyData payload, string timestamp, string signature)
{
    // concat the timestamp header value with the serialized payload
    var stringified = string.Concat(timestamp, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));

    // retrieve secret key
    string secretKey = getSecretKey();

    // compute hash
    var hash = GetAuthHash(stringified, secretKey);

    // do string comparison on the hash and the signature
    return hash == signature;
}

public class MyData 
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public string GetAuthHash(string message, string secret)
{
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    
    using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
    {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `==` between two byte arrays, it's just checking whether or not they refer to the same object. That's not what you want. You need to change *how you compare byte arrays*, not how you create the byte arrays. You should also reconsider how you're coming up with the string, because not every hash is a valid UTF-8 string to start with... if you've previously taken the result of hashing and used `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash)` then you've already got a problem in the data you've stored.

Comment: (It doesn't help that you haven't provided real code - that method signature is invalid. A [mcve] would make it easier to help you.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the original post with a different approach based on this example I've found. Please let me know if I'm on the right track https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#csharp

Comment: Yes, that's better. (Although I'd use `Encoding.UTF8` rather than creating a new instance each time.) Any stored signatures (which presumably *aren't* base64-encoded) will be invalid though.